# Open Toggle App Drawer by default when login in odoo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, odoo-11, webresponse

I am using web responsive theme in odoo 11 now i want is to get App Drawer screen as my default screen when i login.

I have tried changing some code in webresponsive.js

```
    showFoundMenus: function(menus) {
        this.searching = true;
        this.$el.find('#appDrawerApps').hide();
        this.$searchAction.hide();
        this.$el.find('.drawer-search-close').show();
        this.$el.find('.drawer-search-open').hide();
        this.$searchResultsContainer
            // Render the results
            .html(
                core.qweb.render(
                    'AppDrawerMenuSearchResults',
                    {menus: menus}
                )
            )
```

The default screen should be the display of app when we press toggle button on top left